# Send parameter to ViewModel through IDialogService when open new window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have `PersonViewModel`, `DepartmentViewModel` and their `PersonView`, `DepartmentView`.

`PersonViewModel` has empty constructor, however `DepartmentViewModel` has a parameter:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    public DepartmentViewModel(ObservableCollection<Person> persons)
    {}
}
```

I use the following service to open new window:

```
public interface IDialogService<T>
{
   void Show(IUnityContainer unityContainer);
   void ShowDialog(IUnityContainer unityContainer);
}

public class DialogService<T> : IDialogService<T> where T : Window
{
   public void Show(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
   {            
     var container = unityContainer;
     container.Resolve<T>().Show();
   }

   public void ShowDialog(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
   {            
      var container = unityContainer;            
      container.Resolve<T>().ShowDialog();            
   }
}
```

the above service works really good. So far, it works okay till I wanted to send parameters to `DepartmentViewModel`.

My `App.xaml.cs` has all stuff to instantiate viewModels inside of `OnStartup()` method:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
   _container = new UnityContainer();
   _container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MainWindow>();
   _container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MainViewModel>();
   _container.RegisterType<IViewPersonViewModel, PersonView>();
   _container.RegisterType<IViewPersonViewModel, PersonViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   _container.RegisterType<IViewDepartmentViewModel, DepartmentView>();
   _container.RegisterType<IViewDepartmentViewModel, DepartmentViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   //types
   _container.RegisterType(typeof(IDialogService<>), typeof(DialogService<>));
   _container.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
}
```

My question is how can I send a parameter to `DepartmentViewModel` when I open new window from `PersonViewModel`?

My code to open new window from `PersonViewModel`:

```
private readonly IDialogService<DepartmentView> _dialogDepartmentView;

public void ContinueCommand_DoWork(object obj)
{
   //want to send "persons" to departmentViewModel
   ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();           
    // Open new dialog    
   _dialogDepartmentView.ShowDialog(_unityContainer);
}
```

How can I send `ObservableCollection<Person> persons` to `DepartmentViewModel` when I open new window through `IDialogService`?

Comment: Argh. `ServiceLocator` antipattern all over your code. That being said, how many instances of `DepartmentViewModel` do you have? This is the deciding factor on which way you should go for the solution.

Comment: @code4life  just one instance of DepartmentViewModel. Antipattern means bad?

Comment: should try not to use it at all, to be honest.

Comment: @code4life but how can I open new window from viewModel? could you provide a link to see the right approach to open new window.

Comment: @StepUp. There are lots of google hits, and lots of QA in stackoverflow itself. Lots of them suggests going for a mediator pattern. Others suggests services. Others, events, commands etc.. I find services to be more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need a new Dialog/UIService then.

Here's a UiService I use to achieve the same effect as you. I don't use any IoC container. `ViewLocator` is a simple class with a dictionary mapping from Vm type to View type. You could replace ViewLocator with whatever "ServiceLocator" you want ,though.

```
public interface IUiService {
    void Close();
    void Show<TVm>(TVm vm) where TVm : ViewModel;
    public T ShowDialog<T, TVm>(TVm vm) 
        where T : class
        where TVm : ViewModel, IDialogReturnVm<T>;
}

public class UiService : IUiService
{
    private readonly Window window;

    public UiService(Window window)
    {
        this.window = window;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.window.Close();
    }

    public void Show<TVm>(TVm vm) where TVm : ViewModel
    {
        Type windowType = ViewLocator.GetViewType<TVm>()

        var wnd = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(windowType);

        wnd.DataContext = vm;
        wnd.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        vm.Init(new UiService(wnd));
        wnd.Show();
    }

    public T ShowDialog<T, TVm>(TVm vm) 
        where T : class  //T is the type of imformation which the Vm will "return" when it's window is closed.
        where TVm : ViewModel, IDialogReturnVm<T>
    {
        Type windowType = ViewLocator.GetViewType<TVm>()

        var wnd = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(windowType);

        wnd.DataContext = vm;
        wnd.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        vm.Init(new UiService(wnd));
        wnd.ShowDialog();
        return vm.ReturnInfo;
    }
}
```

All of my VMs have an IUiService property which is set when I call it's `Init` method.

In the AppStartup, when I want to open my first window, I do :

```
Type windowType = ViewLocator.GetViewType<MainVm>()

var wnd = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(windowType);

wnd.DataContext = new MainVm();
vm.Init(new UiService(wnd));
wnd.Show();
```

basically same as what I do in the `UiService.Show`.

So when you want to `Show` a ViewModel from another ViewModel, you call `this.UiService.Show(new YourVm(parameters..));`.

`IUiService.Show` will then determine the window type of your VM using the ViewLocator and create a new Window. It also assigns the IUiService for the new VM using that window.

`IDialogReturnVm<T>` is an interface with a single property `T ReturnInfo{get; private set;}` which you set inside your Vm.

This keeps the View and ViewModel decoupled pretty well, while still allowing you to pass parameters to ViewModel. I even have my ViewModels in a different assembly. The `IUiService` is defined in that assembly and the implementation : `UiService` is defined in the main assembly.