# C# using MVVM - Difficult Behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

After spending hours (maybe days) grinding trying to solve, I decided to put my faith in your knowledge. I want to implement this behavior (blue): [image]

So in the **loginButton** I fire a command that is handled in the **loginViewModel** in this handler I do some verifications to a webservice and using that answer I want to open a new Window sending an User (class). How can I do this?

I've tried messaging, I've tried a lot of things. In code behind is something like this that I want to do using MVVM architecture.

**LoginView Code-Behind**

```
 button_OnClick(){
// Checking stuff
    var u = //from the server;
    PrincipalView pv = new PrincipalView(u);
    pv.Show();
    this.Close()
}
```

In the **PrincipalView Code-Behind**:

```
public PrincipalView(User u){
        // Yey, I have the user
  }
```

Comment: So you want to open another view from Viewmodel

Comment: yes, but fired from a command in the LoginViewModel

Comment: actually you can do this by adding the same code in the code behind to your viewmodel, if you want a clean MVVM implementation, there you need to define some services in order to abstract window workflow like show, close...

Comment: To explain further: I don't want just OnClick change Views (I know how to do this in XAML)..I want to fire a command that in the LoginViewModel does some checks to db and after that changes to the PrincipalView (it can be a window or a view inside the mainview) passing the User as parameter.

Comment: But doing this using code-behind then in the PrincipalViewModel how can I get the user passed to the PrincipalView ?

Comment: no you will get the user in the command after the check and then call the view that you want and pass that user, but that's not a clear implmentation MVVM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110849/discussion-between-antoine-and-moez-rebai).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that by using a custom window service class like following:

```
 class WindowsService
{
    private static LoginWindow loginWindow{ get; set; }

    private static UserWindow UserWindow{ get; set; }

    public void ShowLoginWindow(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        LoginWindow = new LoginWindow 
        {
            DataContext = loginViewModel
        };
        LoginWindow.Show();
    }
    public void ShowUserWindow(UserViewModel userViewModel)
    {
        UserWindow = new UserWindow 
        {
            DataContext = userViewModel
        };

        LoginWindow .Hide();
        UserWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

So you declare an instance of **WindowsService** in your **LoginViewModel**, and when your logic find the user you create an instance of your **UserViewModel** and call **windowsService.ShowUserWindow(userViewModel)**. In order to use this properly, you have to modify your **App.xaml.cs file** like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        loginViewModel.StartLoginWindowService();
    }
}
```

The method **StartLoginWindowService()** may look like this:

```
public void StartLoginWindowService()
    {
        WindowsService.ShowLoginWindow(this);
    }
```

Please let me know if this helps

Explaining where to create UserWindowViemodel

Suppose the following method in your loginViewmodel

```
public void Loging(string name, string pass){
  var isAllowed(name, pass); //Check if user exists and if pass is correct
  if(!isAllowed) return; //we return if user is invalid
  var wService = new WindowsService();
  var myUser = new UserWindowViewModel(name){
    //you set all proeperties you need here
  }
  wService.ShowUserWindow(myUser);
}
```

Comment: How can I pass the attributes to the UserWindow? And use that attributes in the UserWindowViewModel?

Comment: When creating the instance of userWindowViewModel in you LoginViewMode, you have to create it with all attributes you need. Then simply call ShowUserWindow(userViewmodel) passing the userWindowViewModel you have just created. If you mean how can you display values of your viewmodel in your view, that is with xaml databinding. Are you familiar to MVVM WPF?

Comment: I'm learning that. I still didn't understand where I will create the instance of UserWindowViewModel

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check it

Comment: give me a sec. I will try but my LoginView is not a window but a view inside a window.

Comment: Doesn´t matter if it is not a window, it is inside a window anyway, so you can call the method always.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ltAr59P.png I'm having troubles, if you see the LoginViewModel is the child of the MainWindowViewModel. Now I created the Hope that is a test window to this behavior :)

Comment: I recommend you to look at Emperor Aiman answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110851/discussion-between-taquion-and-antoine).

Comment: I've tried, but didn't managed to succeed and yours seems quite clear and simple for me. Do you think is not working?

Comment: I just think, that what you want to accomplish could have been easliy done with PRISM's RegionManager and RequestNavigate. It would not cost you so much effort to make it all work, because as I see on your profile, you have a lot of problems with your app. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a service which will open a window when you pass it a ViewModel.

Basically, you will have a `ViewLocator` which will find the specified View for you when you give it a ViewModel. The `UIService` have methods such as `Show` and `ShowDialog` to which you can pass any ViewModel. These methods will then open the registered view and also assign a new UIService for the newly created ViewModel.

I have described the process in detail  in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664490/send-parameter-to-viewmodel-through-idialogservice-when-open-new-window/36670420#36670420).